# How to call function at fixed interval with ensuring previous function is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, setinterval

I have a Promise based function which i want to call at fixed interval, Lets say at every 60 seconds. But i also want to make sure that function is called only if the previously called function is executed completely and i want to continue this for infinite time

```
function fun(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        //Some database queries which may or may not complete in 60 seconds
        resolve("done")
    })
}

setInterval(()=>{
    fun().then(d=>{
        console.log(d)
    })
},60000)
```

Above code will not check for previously called function is completed or not. but i want to make sure that

Comment: If you want to wait until it's completed then you should switch to setTimeout instead

Comment: Just use setTimeout instead of setInterval, and call again.

Comment: Use a global variable to keep track whether fun is executing. Set it to true when it's called, set it to false when the promise is resolved. If the flag is truthy, don't call fun in the interval, otherwise, call it. Otherwise, if you don't mind about timing, just a use setTimeout instead. Besides, there is no async await in your code, is it indended? (it's tagged)

Comment: @briosheje  Do be aware doing that though, you might then have to wait nearly 2 mins before the next check, or the next check might happen instantly after the last.

Comment: @Icepickle  OP wants it to run every 60 seconds, for infinite time.

Comment: @Mirakurun I get that, I also posted an answer to show how he could do it ;)

Comment: @Keith this should never happen, since the variable assignment should take a very few amount of clock cycles, hence the chance is so low that I don't think you should ever consider that scenario at all (if you're talking about concurrency, otherwise, fine). The point is that having a 60 seconds interval is quite.. pointless? (for that approach specifically)

Comment: "_may or may not complete in 60 seconds_" Browsers will usually abort e.g. an AJAX call after 30 secs automatically, if the server hasn't responded within that time.

Comment: @Icepickle If i use setTimeout instead of setInterval, still it will not make sure that the previous called function is completed

Comment: Yes it will, because your telling it to start again when you finished the previous one.

Comment: @Teemu It is for node js, This function will not used in browsers

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the suggestions but that what exactly i want to do

Comment: @briosheje   1. database query, takes 59 seconds, next setInterval kicks in, database query again.  IOW: 1 second between between the previous query and the next, if this is what the OP wants, that's fine.  If using a flag, it will of course potentially miss ones too.  querys takes 1 min 1 second, the second minute will not have a query run.

Comment: @KrunalSonparate  Sorry what is it you want to do?,.  As I see it you have 2 options, if using setInterval it will fire your initial DB query every 1 min, only if the last one was done within 1 min, if not it will miss the next interval.  Alternatively you can say,   "doquery" - "wait1min" - "doquery" - "wait1min", this is better served with setTmeout.  Personally I use the setTimeout method most the time, as I like the idea of giving the DB engine some guaranteed breathing space between query's, if these query's are heavy, or you might end up doing 2 heavy query's one after the other. :(

Comment: @KrunalSonparate Ah ... OK. Node.js is not mentioned in the question, though.

Comment: @Keith I want to do some processing in db at every 60 seconds. so the problem is if i use setInterval with at every 60 seconds it will call at doquery at every 60 seconds but it will still doquery if previous data query is not completed. so i just want to make sure that it doquery at every 60 seconds and if doquery takes time of 65 seconds that doquery after 65 seconds but if doquery completed in 40 seconds than i want to doquery at after 20 seconds of prevoud doquery

Comment: I will be happy if i can use mutex here. it will work for me

Comment: So if the query takes 65 seconds, what do you want to do it's not clear..  1.  Run next query instantly, 2. wait 55 seconds for the next one?.   If you do 1, you could of course end up chasing your tail.  Not sure sure how a mutex is going to help you here, it's nothing to do with threading.  Also it's worth thinking in terms of worst case scenario, if your query constantly takes 59 seconds to complete, you will basically be pegging your DB server at 100% processing this query constantly.

Comment: If the query uses 65 seconds then i want to call next query at instantly. I am sure that at every time it will not take more than 59 seconds

Comment: Ah, in that case you will need to use a stack.  But be aware the chasing tail problem, this stack could just end up getting bigger & bigger.  eg..  If every query takes 65 seconds, the stack will just grow & grow.  If this is something you really want, I could post a simple snippet showing how you can do this.  And of course if this stack is always full, your basically running the query constantly..

Comment: @Krunal then just avoid using intervals. Make a queue or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class AsyncQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.queue = null;
  }

  push(task) {
    // If we have task in query, append new at the end, if not execute immediately
    // Every task appended to existing queue will be executed immediately after previous one is finished
    return this.queue = this.queue ? this.queue.then(() => task()) : task();
  }
}

const task = (id) => () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log('Task', id, 'started');
  // Random time betwen 500-1300ms
  const time = Math.round(Math.random() * 800 + 500);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Finished task '" + id + "' after " + time + "ms");
    resolve();
  }, time);
});
const queue = new AsyncQueue();
let id = 0;
// This will push new task to queue every 1s
setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Pushing new task", ++id);
  queue.push(task(id));
}, 1000);
```

Of course we can implement it without using class

```
let queue;
function push(task) {
  return queue = queue ? queue.then(() => task()) : task();
}
// or
const push = (task) => queue = queue ? queue.then(() => task()) : task();
```

Comment: Nice solution :)

Comment: @Icepickle thanks, I don't like to complicate things

Comment: @ponury-kostek Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to wait until it has finished, you should call it again after the promise has resolved. So you would then change from `setInterval` to `setTimeout` instead.

For the purpose of this question, I did change the timeout to 1 second instead

```js
function fun(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        //Some database queries which may or may not complete in 60 seconds
        resolve("done")
    })
}

function self() {
  setTimeout(()=>{
      fun().then(d=>{
          console.log(d)
      }).then( self ); // call the setTimeout function again
  },1000);
}

self();
```

Of course, choose a better name than `self`, it was like the only thing I could come up with on short notice :)

**Update**

I think I misunderstood the question originally, so you only want to call it again if it really did complete, and not wait until it finished and then have the new interval start.

In that case, you can rather do something like this instead:

```js
function fun(){
  fun.running = true;
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      //Some database queries which may or may not complete in 60 seconds
      resolve("done");
  });
}

setInterval(()=>{
  // just make sure the fun isn't running
  if (!fun.running) {
    fun()
      .then(d=> console.log(d) )
      .catch( err => console.log( err ) ) // error handling here to make sure the next block is run
      .then( () => {
        // and handle the reset of the flag here
        fun.running = false;
      } );
  }
},1000);
```

Comment: This solution will not work for me. It will add time of execution of that function also so it will not called at every 1000 ms

Comment: @KrunalSonparate Sorry, I believe I misunderstood your initial question, but I have updated my answer to mark it using a flag on the function

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the function in setInterval call it with setTimeout after response is received.

```js
function fun(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        //Some database queries which may or may not complete in 60 seconds
        resolve("done")
    })
}
//Function to call promise function recursively
function functionCaller(fn){
fn()
.then((response)=>{
   console.log(response)
   setTimeout(() => functionCaller(fn), 6000)
})
}

functionCaller(fun)
```